# How to index company names in figures?

Tags: imakeidx, makeindex

I am writing an article in TeX and use the `imakeidx` package to generate an index at the end of my document. This works well as long as the selected word is in the text. However, I also have a lot of figures in my text that are shown together on different pages and, sometimes, also three pages in a row.

How can I "index" the companys that are shown in those figures, i.e. to fix that the `\index` command refers to the same page on which the figure is shown? In my current example, if I paste the `\index{company 1}`... directly BEFORE the figure, the index refers to page 2 and if I paste the `\index{company 1}`... directly AFTER the figure, the index refers to page 5 (although the figure is shown on page 4).

Comment: How exactly do you make a figure span multiple pages? That is not standard in LaTeX, and your approach for this may influence the solution for indexing.

Comment: Sorry for being not precise...I have pages with text only and pages with figures only (due to their size). So it is not a figure that spans many pages, but e.g., 6 figures on 3 pages in a row.

Comment: Do the figures have captions? In that case placing the index in the caption might be an option.

Comment: In any case, from the questions that I ask you can see that it would be helpful to add a small but complete example document that illustrates your situation, because such a document would answer all clarification questions automatically. For figures you can use `\includegraphics{example-image}`, this is an example image file that is available in every LaTeX installation, so it is convenient for sharing code. Just make a document with three pages of images and an index, and describe what you want the output to be.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! Placing the index in the caption works great!
Moreover, I was not aware of the example image file and thus, I did not post a MWE. I will definitely do so in the future!

Comment: Actually, it should be possible to put the index entry just after the caption, as opposed to within the caption itself.  If any of these index terms contain macros, this placement may be less likely to cause problems.